# Hanging exec in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to figure out why my subprocess execution sometimes hangs. I'm running the following code to execute a command with privilege drop:

```
def safe_exec(q, uid, gid):
    try:
        os.setgroups([])
        os.setregid(gid, gid)
        os.setreuid(uid, uid)

        print("dropped")
        res = subprocess.check_output(['nm', '-D', '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'])
        print("executed")
        q.put(res)
    except Exception as e:
        q.put(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nobody = pwd.getpwnam('nobody')
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=safe_exec,
            args=(q, nobody.pw_uid, nobody.pw_gid))

    p.start()
    p.join(10)
    res = q.get(False)
    if isinstance(res, Exception):
        raise res
    else:
        print(res)
```

The hang doesn't happen with all commands, but I can reliably reproduce it with `nm -D .../libc.so.6` on my machine. The problem is that the hang happens at the end of `safe_exec` - I can see both "dropped" and "executed" printed out, while the process is still hanging.

Strace shows the following (abbreviated). The child starts and inits as expected:

```
48858 clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f9aa3eab9d0) = 48859
48859 setgroups(0, [])                  = 0
48859 setregid(65534, 65534)            = 0
48859 setreuid(65534, 65534)            = 0
48859 fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 6), ...}) = 0
48859 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9aa3ec2000
48859 write(1, "dropped\n", 8)          = 8
```

The parent starts trying to join by now:

```
48858 wait4(48859,  <unfinished ...>
...
48858 wait4(48859, 0x7fffa52cc07c, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
48859 <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 48860
```

The `subprocess.check_output()` ends and "executed" is reported:

```
48859 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=48860, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
48859 write(1, "executed\n", 9)         = 9
```

Main process starts increasing the timeouts and just waiting. `select`/`wait4` cycles until 10 seconds pass.

```
48858 wait4(48859, 0x7fffa52cc07c, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
48858 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 16000}) = 0 (Timeout)
48858 wait4(48859, 0x7fffa52cc07c, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
48858 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 32000}) = 0 (Timeout)
48858 wait4(48859, 0x7fffa52cc07c, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
48858 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 50000}) = 0 (Timeout)
48858 wait4(48859, 0x7fffa52cc07c, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
48858 select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 50000}) = 0 (Timeout)
[ + many more ]
```

Until `safe_exec` finally finishes, right after the main process gives up on `.join(10)`:

```
48858 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=48859, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
48858 wait4(48859, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 48859
```

And that's it - normal process exit. I can't see what's wrong in this case. Nothing seems to obviously fail.

Looking at the running processes with gdb, the parent is stuck on `wait` inside `join`:

```
#0  0x00007fde4486b6d3 in __select_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x000000000062dbd6 in floatsleep (secs=0) at ../Modules/timemodule.c:948
#2  0x000000000062c843 in time_sleep (self=0x0, args=(<float at remote 0x1e15620>,)) at ../Modules/timemodule.c:206
#3  0x00000000004896f9 in PyCFunction_Call (func=<built-in function sleep>, arg=(<float at remote 0x1e15620>,), kw=0x0) at ../Objects/methodobject.c:81
#4  0x000000000052ff77 in call_function (pp_stack=0x7fff39cdc9f0, oparg=1) at ../Python/ceval.c:4356
#5  0x000000000052a7f7 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=Frame 0x1f643d0, for file /usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py, line 165, in wait (self=<Popen(returncode=None, pid=67389) at remote 0x7fde43a83ed0>, timeout=20, deadline=<float at remote 0x1e15558>, delay=<float at remote 0x1e15620>, res=None, remaining=<float at remote 0x1e154e0>), throwflag=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2993
```

and the child is also waiting on finalising the join:

```
#0  0x00007f96798520c9 in futex_abstimed_wait (cancel=true, private=<optimised out>, abstime=0x0, expected=0, futex=0x1c109c0) at sem_waitcommon.c:42
#1  do_futex_wait (sem=sem@entry=0x1c109c0, abstime=0x0) at sem_waitcommon.c:208
#2  0x00007f9679852164 in __new_sem_wait_slow (sem=0x1c109c0, abstime=0x0) at sem_waitcommon.c:277
#3  0x00007f967985220a in __new_sem_wait (sem=<optimised out>) at sem_wait.c:28
#4  0x00000000005787f5 in PyThread_acquire_lock (lock=0x1c109c0, waitflag=1) at ../Python/thread_pthread.h:324
#5  0x000000000062aa9f in lock_PyThread_acquire_lock (self=0x7f9679c21c70, args=()) at ../Modules/threadmodule.c:52
#6  0x00000000004896f9 in PyCFunction_Call (func=<built-in method acquire of thread.lock object at remote 0x7f9679c21c70>, arg=(), kw=0x0) at ../Objects/methodobject.c:81
#7  0x000000000052ff77 in call_function (pp_stack=0x7ffda823dce0, oparg=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:4356
#8  0x000000000052a7f7 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=Frame 0x1c107b0, for file /usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py, line 340, in wait (self=<_Condition(_Verbose__verbose=False, _Condition__lock=<thread.lock at remote 0x7f9679c21c20>, acquire=<built-in method acquire of thread.lock object at remote 0x7f9679c21c20>, _Condition__waiters=[<thread.lock at remote 0x7f9679c21c70>], release=<built-in method release of thread.lock object at remote 0x7f9679c21c20>) at remote 0x7f9676cec1b0>, timeout=None, waiter=<thread.lock at remote 0x7f9679c21c70>, saved_state=None), throwflag=0)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:2993
```

The python stack in the child being:

```
_Condition.wait
Thread.join
Queue._finalize_join
Finalize.__call__
```

I'd appreciate any ideas on why is that process hanging for so long.

The code was run on python 2.7 and 3.4

Comment: Looks like it's connected with a `Queue` object - either yours or some other that `multiprocess` uses behind the scenes. E.g. does `q.put(res)` get executed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that small, or empty results sent on the queue were handled correctly, but long results were not and were blocking the process join.

The issue is solved/worked around by getting the result off the queue before joining.